# QBasicTimer can be used with threads started with QThread when selecting widget.setFocus(True)

Tags: pyqt5, qt5

I always get this error message.

QBasicTimer can be used with threads started with QThread when widget.setFocus()
Basically, I have a class Rotary which is listening to GPIO.
it has myForm.dial_on_value_changed() registered as a callback to Rotary which will call dial_on_value_changed() when rotator is rotated.

If **myForm.dial_on_value_changed()** only prints a text or string then it is fine. But if it selected one of myForm element and change its state such as ***setFocus(True)***, it will throw the above error, smth related with QThread.

My Application is a single thread and Rotari itself works based on listening to an interrupt in a GPIO pin which will call the registered callback function.

can someone tell me or guide me what I have done wrong? Or maybe a better way to solve this problem which is "A knob which will rotate and set all GUI element to be focused"

thanks in advance.

This is my snippet code

```
 class MyForm(QDialog):
   ### creating a circular list
   self._vt_dial_cycle = cycle([
        # tuple UI element with a function
        (self.vt_textedit, self.dial_to_vt),
        (self.rr_textedit, self.dial_to_rr),
        (self.stop_button, None),
        (self.start_button, None),
        (self.ie_textedit, self.dial_to_ie)
   ])


   def dial_to_vt(self):
       print("Dial on vt")

   def dial_to_rr(self):
       print("Dial on rr")
  
   def dial_to_ie(self):
       print("Dial on ie")

   def dial_on_value_changed(self, direction):
       # get next element from circular list.
       (active_widget, action) = next(self._vt_dial_cycle)
       self._current_widget = (active_widget, action)

       #execute action manually registered with widget
       action()

       if isinstance(active_widget, QTextEdit):
           self.move_cursor_to_end(active_widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()

    # ... a rotari with a knop 
    ky040 = KY040(CLOCKPIN, DATAPIN, SWITCHPIN, w.dial_on_value_changed, w.dial_on_pressed)
    
    ky040.start()
```

Comment: You said that you're using only one thread, but from the error (which you didn't report correctly, by the way: please be more careful with copy/paste of error messages) and your description, that `KY040` seems *a lot* like something that has its own thread, and if that's the case, then you already have your answer: you cannot access UI elements from external threads.

Comment: Let say if I can't access UI elements from external threads, how can I handle any input from let say GPIO? Should I do some sort of pooling on that specific pin? KY040 is a wrapper that wrap GPIO library which registers a callback  if one of io pin changes its state. Could you give me a suggestion what should I do?

Comment: Use a QThread with a custom signal, and use the signals `emit` as function arguments to call when the GPIO is triggered, and start it in the `run()` of the QThread. Then connect the thread's signals with the functions that actually interact with widgets. Do some research on terms like QThread, worker and custom signals, as there are literally hundreds of posts about these topics.

Comment: Many thanks. I read this book Qt5-Python-GUI-Programming. It helps me to understand.